# I have a problem installing a library in a python language

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
 Using cached bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
```

What is the problem with installing the library bs4 I have

Comment: bs4 isn't the correct package for beautifulsoup

Comment: What should I do? It is in the IBM course

Comment: You didn't show us the command you ran. You didn't tell us where you got that file. And, as @OneCricketeer pointed out, `bs4` is not the name of the Python package. See https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/. If some course you are taking told you to install that compressed tarball you should contact the people who wrote the course.

Comment: Courses can go out of date. Find the actual library docs https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-beautiful-soup